# iOS Siri add custom vocabulary

Tags: ios, xcode, siri

I have some troubles to add custom vocabulary to Siri.

I have implemented Siri in my app and it works well with classical commands. However, I tried to add a custom phrase and it doesn't recognized it. 
I tried the two ways described in "https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/SpecifyingCustomVocabulary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH6-SW1" and followed all the steps.

Do you have any other tips or explanations ? Or could you tell me how I can debug this because I have no clue of what happening, if my AppIntentVocabulary.plist is taken into account or not for exemple.

Comment: Do you have news about this one? I am very interested as I am facing similar issues

Answer (score 0):

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48861352/1351327.
A lot of people faced this problem like me in the past.
We should wait Apple to add new intent domains. Open radar has so many requests for that.