# how do i create and use custom vocabulary with sirikit?

Tags: xcode, siri

[image]

I want Siri to show me specific content in `IntentViewController` of Siri on my specific Command. I have tried adding a `.plist` to `.lproj` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please include details of what you tried.

Comment: @sorak I have added a screenshot of  .plist plz take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not understand what you want to do so I want to give an advice that you can't use **INSendMessageIntent** outside of its capabilities. That means you should use some keywords for your custom sentences to make Siri understand your custom command for the INSendMessageIntent.

After you created the **AppIntentVocabulary.plist** file, it needs to be send to the **Apple Siri Servers**. You can achieve this by changing your iPhone Siri language to a different one that you know, then use a simple siri message process with that language. 

Then again change it to the language you want.

Do this each time you change the AppIntentVocabulary.plist.

Comment: I wanted to display the chart in IntentViewController's view area by saying "show me chart".is that possible?

Comment: does Siri support chart data be displayed?

Comment: As I know INSendMessageIntent can not be used like your aim. From my experience you should use the "Send a message..." keyword. In the past I wanted to a different process with INSendMessageIntent  like you and I could not achieve it.

Comment: I don't know there exists an official Siri command list but you can look here https://www.cnet.com/how-to/the-complete-list-of-siri-commands/

Comment: Thank you @ondermerol but I don't think INSendMessageIntent gonna work for my aim.Can CustomVocabulary help me out?

Comment: No it can not help, you can not do what you want.

Comment: @varsha.shivhare: you can do it using Siri Shortcuts now.

Comment: @DungeonDev the user should create a voice command outside of the application for it.